How can the system time and computer time be different locally in .net core API?
I am running a .net core API project locally on my Windows machine, local time is utc +3. In the response header returned from the requests, the results are returned according to utc + 0.
This time difference causes me to get an error when validating my jwt tokens, I can never validate them.
For example:
local time : 15:45:51
(kestrel) .net time : 12:45:51
I tried TimeZoneInfo but it didn't work. It did not make sense for me to make transactions by seeing the time difference when I gave UTCnow while specifying the token durations. I want to see and follow these transactions in my own time zone.
Is it possible to match the system time in .net with my local time?
Updated:
enter image description here
Even though I set an expiration date with datetime.now, it receives the value utcnow as the date and it can never be valid according to this period.
My active time is 16:24
var minute = Convert.ToInt32(_configuration["JwtSettings:ExpirationInMinutes"]);
            token.Expiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(minute);

            JwtSecurityToken securityToken = new(
                audience: _configuration["JwtSettings:Audience"],
                issuer: _configuration["JwtSettings:Issuer"],
                expires: token.Expiration,
                notBefore: DateTime.Now,
                signingCredentials: signingCredentials
                );

If I determine the dates here with UtcNow, it works correctly with a difference with the local time, but how and why can it convert the Datetime.Now value I give to its own UtcNow?

What are you doing to validate your tokens? If you store DateTimeOffset then they should still validate.

@Charlieface I updated the question and tried to be clearer and clearer

Why wouldn't you just use DateTime.UtcNow in all cases? Why do you need the local time?

I agree with @Charlieface why do you need the local time? However the question is still valid for curiosity.
